# Why is my VPC missing from the DB replica wizard?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

In AWS, I'm creating a Read Replica DB, using the `actions` option in the console UI.

Source information -
region/az: `us-west-2b`

Destination information -
region: `us-east-2`

I have 2 VPCs in the `east-2` region, but only one of them shows up in the drop-down list for the DB target. [in addition to the `default` VPC] .
It appears both VPCs are setup the same, so I'm not sure why only one would show.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was mistakingly thinking the drop-down list was for VPCs.

The VPCs aren't listed as a target - it's a 'DB Subnet group' that is created, and allows the connection to the VPC.

The DB subnet group needs to be created prior to creating the DB read replica.

When setting up an Aurora DB POC, this was done automatically, so the original VPC had an entry in the list.